# Piglatin translator, getting a single error, constructor Piglatin() undefined

Tags: java

Alright, I have a homework assignment in which I am to create a class Piglatin so that PigDriver will translate English sentences to Piglatin, I have written it to almost the point of completion, however I am getting one error in the driver:

constructor Piglatin() is undefined

Here is the Driver:

```
import java.util.*;
public class PigDriver{
  public static void main(String[] args){
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   String t = " ";
   Piglatin p = new Piglatin();
   while(t.length() > 0){
     t = scan.nextLine();
     t = t.toLowerCase();
     p.pigConvert(t);
   }
   p.pigReport();
  }
}
```

Here is the class:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

 public class Piglatin{

  public String[] phrases;
  public String result;
  public String s;
  public String token;
  StringTokenizer str;

  public Piglatin(String[] array){
    phrases = array;
  }

  public String pigAll(){
    result="";
    StringTokenizer str;
    while(s!=null){
      for(int j=0; j<phrases.length; j++){
        str = new StringTokenizer(s,"\t\n\r\f,.?!;: ");
        s=phrases[j];
        while(str.hasMoreTokens()){
          result += " ";
          result += pigConvert(str.nextToken());
        } 
      }  
    }return result;}


  public String pigConvert(String token){
    token=str.nextToken();
    token=token.toLowerCase();
    if((token.charAt(0)=='a' || token.charAt(0)=='e' || token.charAt(0)=='i' ||
        token.charAt(0)=='o' || token.charAt(0)=='u')){
      token = (token+"ay");
    }
    else{
      token = token.substring(1) + "ay"; 
    }
    return token;
  }

  public void pigReport(){
    System.out.println(pigAll());
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `PigLatin` constructor requires an array, but you aren't passing it one. Either pass it an array or  create a no args constructor `public Piglatin() {}`.

Comment: Don't be shy, tell us the error.

Comment: Chief, the error is posted above the code

Comment: taken, what do you mean pass it an array?

Comment: Your constructor looks like this `public Piglatin(String[] array) { }`. That means you have to give it an array, something along the lines of `new PigLatin(someRandomStringArray);` where you create a String array named `someRandomStringArray` then populate it with Strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Constructor undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689902/java-constructor-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of responding to your question. 
Your constructor looks like this

```
public Piglatin(String[] array)
```

When you create your object you used

```
Piglatin p = new Piglatin();
```

What you want to do is something like this:

```
String[] array = new String[];
//fill array with values
Piglatin p = new PigLatin(array);
```

because your constructor accepts a parameter and you don't have a constructor that accepts 0 parameters, there is an error thrown.