# I am getting a getInstance() error occurs when trying to create a Singleton

Tags: java, singleton

I know there is lots online and I have been looking for the last two hours trying to fix my code.

I am making a immutable class called Car I have seen lots of videos and read articles online.

Even my notes from college talk about creating a Singleton class when make a class `Immutable` (my notes are rubbish as usual).

Anyway the code below has everything I have seen in videos and read in articles the only difference is in everything I watched and read is their Objects did not have other variables.

```
public final class Car{
    private static Car carSingleton = null;
    private final String owner;
    private final String reg;
    private final String make;
    private final int kilometres;
    private final double price;



    private Car() {}    


    public static Car getInstance()() {
        if(carSingleton == null) {
            carSingleton = new Car();
        }   
        return carSingleton;
    }



    public String getOwner(){return owner;}
    public String getReg(){return reg;}
    public String getMake(){return make;}
    public int getKilometres(){return kilometres;}
    public double getPrice(){return price;}



}
```

I am getting a an error in the `getInstance()` constructor Car() is undefined.

EDIT:
Here is the actual question I was given

Question 1
Given below is a mutable Car class. Re-write it so that it becomes immutable and write a simple test program.

```
class Car{
    private String owner;
    private String reg;
    private String make;
    private int kilometres;
    private double price;
    public Car(String owner, String reg, String make, int kilometres, double price){
            this.owner = owner; this.reg = reg;this.make = make; 
            this.kilometres = kilometres; this.price = price; 
    }
    public String owner(){return owner;}
    public String reg(){return reg;}
    public String make(){return make;}
    public intkilometres(){return kilometres;}
    public double price(){return price;}
    public void setPrice(double p){price = p;}
    public void setOwner(String ow){owner = ow;}
    public void setKil(int k){kilometres = k;}
    public void setMake(String m){make = m;}
}
```

Comment: What "owner" should that instance of Car returned by `getInstancen()` have? And what "price"? To make it short, using a singleton for such a class makes no sense.

Comment: You're getting that exception because there isn't a zero parameter constructor.  This must be happening during compile time?  Other things of note, `getInstancen()` is slightly misspelled if you care.  The constructor for car, if it is a singlton should be private.  To fix the problem call the Car constructor passing in some values and it should work fine(ish).

Comment: `getInstancen()` is not `getInstance()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Constructor undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689902/java-constructor-undefined)

Comment: Also suitable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159104/java-error-the-constructor-is-undefined

Comment: Thank you all, I have created a default constructor but I am getting an error telling me that all of the final variables are not initialized??

Comment: so why are they final? Why is there only going to be one car?

Comment: @ Scary Wombat: Its my assignment Ill edit the question and put the full question in.

Comment: so is a `Car` with owner `Liam` the same instance as a `Car` with owner `Fred`?  Pretty nonsensical I think.  Could the values of the fields be hard-coded? `private final String owner = "Fred";`  BTW, you could also change `getInstance` to accept paramaters which could be passed to the old constrcutor (if not already instantiated)

Comment: @ Scary Wombat: It leads onto the second question, its these silly assignments we get in college I  know we have to learn but the questions are just pointless sometimes

Comment: OK, to make it mutable keep the original code and just remove the setters.  You are confusing us and yourself by introducing the concept of Singleton.  See my answer below

Comment: Don't edit your post to add more questions. You can only ask one question per post. For more you need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this class immutable remove the setters.  It should not be Singleton.

```
class Car{
    private String owner;
    private String reg;
    private String make;
    private int kilometres;
    private double price;
    public Car(String owner, String reg, String make, int kilometres, double price){
            this.owner = owner; this.reg = reg;this.make = make; 
            this.kilometres = kilometres; this.price = price; 
    }
    public String getOwner(){return owner;}
    public String getReg(){return reg;}
    public String getMake(){return make;}
    public getKilometres(){return kilometres;}
    public double getPrice(){return price;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `getInstance()` you are calling a constructor which is not defined:

```
carSingleton = new Car();
```

Define a default constructor to fix the error:

```
private Car() {
    // initialize final variables
}
```

or use some other constructor in getInstance()

Answering the EDIT part:

If a type (class) is immutable it only means you can't change its instances once you create them. Only thing you need to do in your assignment is remove all of the **set** methods and make all class attributes `final`.

Like you said, your notes are not helping you at all. Singleton should not be used for this purpose.